# Separate list items by their class or kind_of in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, split

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ["a","b","c"]
```

my list `l` is:

```
l = [a,b].flatten
```

so `l = [1,2,3,"a","b","c"]`

I'm looking for an elegant way of splitting the list by the type of the items in it, in order to have `a` and `b` restored as they were.

I could go with each item in the list and test, but that doesn't seem efficient runtime-wise nor code-wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`group_by`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and then pull your arrays out of the resulting Hash:

```
>> by_class = l.group_by(&:class)
=> {Integer=>[1, 2, 3], String=>["a", "b", "c"]}
>> a = by_class[Fixnum]
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> b = by_class[String]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

If you know that you only have Fixnums and Strings then you could use [`partition`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
>> a, b = *l.partition { |o| o.is_a? Fixnum }
=> [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]]
>> a
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> b
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```